# MySQL Sort By 2 Columns

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

I have a table which holds information on television programs and I want to order it by Seasons and then by episodes. Here's a basic view of what I have:

```
+---+--------+---------+
|id | Season | Episode |
+---+--------+---------+
| 1 |    1   |    1    |
+---+--------+---------+
| 1 |    1   |    2    |
+---+--------+---------+
| 1 |    2   |    1    |
+---+--------+---------+
| 1 |    2   |    3    |
+---+--------+---------+
```

So I select what I need and order by Season. But there's going to be a lot between seasons so I need to sort episodes too, but without it affecting seasons.

Comment: I think what you meant is "columns" not "tables" - the table is what holds all this data, a column is "season", "episode", etc.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP MySQL Order by Two Columns](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/514943/php-mysql-order-by-two-columns)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Do you mean:

```
SELECT id, Season, Episode 
FROM table 
ORDER BY Season ASC, Epsisode ASC
```

Sorting by multiple columns is as simple as it gets.

Comment: Yes I meant columns. Im too tired to use the right terminolagy :p

Answer (score 4):

We know what you mean :)
In your order by you should have

```
ORDER BY Season, Episode
```

It will sort by Season and then on Episode within Season