# Best way to sort MySql results based on two columns and show results using pagination?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, zend-framework, pagination

I want to sort results set first based on one column and then based on second column. I know [how to do it on server side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/944134/mysql-sort-by-2-columns). And then I want to show these results with pagination feature.

Question: would it be better to do it on client side via ajax in jQuery? I'm using Zend Framework. Would Zend_Paginator module be useful in this scenario? I mean if unordered set is returned by server then using jquery to sort results based on any two columns would be better option, I think? How can I do that?

Basically I want to evaluate all the possible ways. Which one would be best and/or simplest option given I'm using jQuery and Zend Framework?

Comment: Don't try to "evaluate all the possible ways". Some of these ways could be tricky ones. Try to evaluate *sensible* ways instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are going to send the whole result to client. You can use a Jquery plugin eg. [Datatable](http://www.datatables.net/). It can paginate and sort

otherwise to sort and paginate in mysql, the sql would look like:

```
SELECT * FROM data SORT BY first_column ASC, second_column DESC LIMIT 20, 10
```

LIMIT 20, 10, means , select 10 rows at offset of 20, which means, show 10 rows in page 3

Comment: Accepted this answer. I fount this link http://www.packtpub.com/article/jquery-table-manipulation-part2 useful.