# PHP Order by multiple columns

Tags: sql, sql-order-by

I need an SQL query that orders a column by a ranking system, but if the ranks are the same, use the id as only a secondary, last resort order. Can anyone help me accomplish this? I have the system working with ORDER BY, but if rankings are the same, it screws up the system. I only need the primary, secondary ORDER BY code and not a whole query.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP MySQL Order by Two Columns](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/514943/php-mysql-order-by-two-columns)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to specify two conditions (separated by commas) in your ORDER BY clause:

```
ORDER BY ranking, id
```

Comment: I have tried that, but it is not giving me the correct entry from the database.

Comment: @user981053 then you need to give us more information - edit the question with an example of the data and what you want.

Comment: I figured it out. I was using (ORDER BY rank, id DESC) instead of using (ORDER BY rank DESC, id DESC). Thank you for the help.