# MySQL multiple column asc order

Tags: mysql, sql, select, sql-order-by

I am trying to run this query in ascending order:

```
SELECT title,project_index 
FROM projectdetail  
WHERE project_index BETWEEN 1 AND 6 
ORDER BY title, project_index ASC;
```

I need two columns in ascending order, but the above query returns results with only one column in `ASC` order.

Comment: I don't get your question completely. But you can specify the order for every column like `order by col1 asc, col2 asc, col3 desc` and so on

Comment: i tried but its not working for me.. my query is title,project_index these two columns i want to display asc order but only one columns taking effect....

Comment: Please show your query output.

Comment: Maybe OP is thinking about ORDER BY project_index, title; ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP MySQL Order by Two Columns](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/514943/php-mysql-order-by-two-columns)

Comment: Mr.user1135693, Have you found any solution? Because I am also facing same issue.

Answer (score 28):

Ascending order is the **default** for most *(if not all)* DBMS's so your statement is kind of *weird* in that respect but nevertheless, you can specify an order for each individual column by adding the specifier `ASC` or `DESC` to it.

Your statement then would become

```
SELECT  title
        , project_index 
FROM    projectdetail 
WHERE   project_index BETWEEN 1 AND 6 
ORDER BY 
        title ASC
        , project_index ASC
```

**Edit**

As been mentioned by @Arvo & @Dems, currently you are sorting **first** on `title` and for identical titles on `project_index`. If you want your `project_index` sorted first, you have to place it first in the `ORDER BY` clause.

Your statement then becomes

```
SELECT  title
        , project_index 
FROM    projectdetail 
WHERE   project_index BETWEEN 1 AND 6 
ORDER BY 
        project_index ASC
        , title ASC
```

and because `ASC` is the default sort order, you can omit them alltogether

```
SELECT  title
        , project_index 
FROM    projectdetail 
WHERE   project_index BETWEEN 1 AND 6 
ORDER BY 
        project_index
        , title
```

Comment: @user1135693 - Can you post your query and results? Either there's something wrong with the query or you've stumbled upon a bug.

Comment: my query SELECT title,project_index FROM projectdetail  WHERE project_index BETWEEN 1 AND 6 ORDER BY title ASC,project_index ASC;

Comment: title asc its coming BUT project index it has to show 1 to 6 but it shwoing 6 to 1

Comment: @user1135693 - and your (relevant) results?

Comment: title-->apple,cat,doll,elep   project_index-->6,5,4,3,2,1  like results displaying but i want project_index-->1,2,3,4,5,6

Comment: @user1135693 - If `apple` has multiple record with different project indexes, this will put the lowest project index first.  If you want all the project index (1) records first, regardles of name, you need to order by project_index first...  (`ORDER BY prroject_index, title`)

Answer (score 4):

If you are using mysql, check [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/order-by-optimization.html) out.

As they say there, you can use `SELECT * FROM t1 ORDER BY key_part1 DESC, key_part2 ASC;`

Comment: thanks for reply.....but still i am facing this issues i tried above all but still.......

Answer (score 3):

> ORDER BY title ASC, project_index ASC;

```
 SELECT title,project_index 
 FROM projectdetail  
 WHERE project_index BETWEEN 1 AND 6 
 ORDER BY title ASC, project_index ASC;
```

AND you can add more columns like `ORDER BY col1 ASC, col2 ASC, col3 DESC;`

Answer (score 0):

You try to sort both columns in ascending order. In mysql, you can use multiple order in a query. But the preference for the order by is very important here. First one get the most preference and next one get second preference. 

That means, Your query is

```
SELECT title,project_index FROM projectdetail  
    WHERE project_index BETWEEN 1 AND 6 ORDER BY title, project_index ASC;
```

Where, order by title got first preference. The mysql will order the 'title' column in ascending order at first and display the result. Then only it will order 'project_index' column. So you cann't get answer as you want.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT title, project_index 
FROM projectdetail  
WHERE project_index BETWEEN 1 AND 6 
ORDER BY project_index, title;
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try with the below and check--

```
SELECT title,project_index 
FROM projectdetail  
WHERE project_index BETWEEN 1 AND 6 
ORDER BY title, project_index
```

Answer (score -1):

As per your requirement/query i think it is impossible to do ordering more than 2 columns in same table. If you want to order based on value you can do like this.

```
SELECT lat,lon, title, zip, city, state, region,cantone 
FROM company 
WHERE title != '' AND state IN(1,3,4,5,6,7,9,2) 
ORDER BY state=2,title asc
```

In above query it will first show all title in ascending order except state=2 and then shows all records with state=2 in last.

Answer (score -1):

Use

```
    ORDER BY title ASC,project_index ASC
```

instead of

```
    ORDER BY title, project_index ASC;
```

give the order separately for both then it will work properly.