# Set multiple order by in mysql query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I have a table of **users** which contain some information of users.

```
id  |   name  |  country
------------------------------
1   |  user1  |  India
2   |  user2  |  China
3   |  user3  |  United State
4   |  user4  |  India
5   |  user5  |  Shri Lanka
6   |  user6  |  China
7   |  user7  |  India
```

I want to make a search for users and write a Mysql query.The users list i want like **order by id desc** but if the users of country China should come at last.

```
select * from users order by id desc
```

This query gives me the result in descending order but i don't know what i write about country.

My Output should like

```
id  |   name  |  country
------------------------------
7   |  user7  |  India
5   |  user5  |  Shri Lanka
4   |  user4  |  India
3   |  user3  |  United State
1   |  user1  |  India
6   |  user6  |  China
2   |  user2  |  China
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL multiple column asc order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9063135/mysql-multiple-column-asc-order)

Comment: I want my output like last table i created.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use conditional ordering :

```
ORDER BY t.country = 'China', // 1 if true, 0 if false, ordered ASC 
         t.id DESC
```

MySQL accepts boolean expressions , so `t.country = 'China'` will be 1 if true, and 0 if false.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following

```
SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY country = 'China',id DESC
```

The **conditional ordering** can satisfy your issue .

Comment: What is different here from my answer?

Comment: if the answer is use ful kindly upvote it @HarshwardhanSharma