# MySQL Order by Two Columns

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a Table Like Below

```
    CREATE TABLE Products(Product_id INT, ProductName VARCHAR(255), 
                          Featured enum('Yes', 'No'), Priority enum('p1', 'p2', 'p3'))


    INSERT INTO Products(ProductName, Featured, Priority) 
                  VALUES('Product A', 'Yes', 'p1'),
                        ('Product B', 'No',  'p2'),
                        ('Product C', 'Yes', 'p1'),
                        ('Product D', 'No',  'p1'),
                        ('Product E', 'Yes', 'p3'),
                        ('Product F', 'No',  'p2'),
                        ('Product G', 'Yes', 'p1'),
                        ('Product H', 'Yes', 'p2'),
                        ('Product I', 'No',  'p2'),
                        ('Product J', 'Yes', 'p3'),
                        ('Product K', 'Yes', 'p1'),
                        ('Product L', 'No',  'p3');
```

I Need to get the Featured products followed by product with priority p1, p2 and p3

```
Op:
   ProdName | Featured  | Priority

    Product A   Yes         p1
    Product C   Yes         p1
    Product G   Yes         p1
    Product K   Yes         p1
    Product H   Yes         p2
    Product E   Yes         p3
    Product J   Yes         p3
    Product D   No          p1
    Product B   No          p2
    Product F   No          p2
    Product I   No          p2
    Product L   No          p3
```

I Wrote a query below which ain't working..

```
                                           
  SELECT * 
    FROM Products
   ORDER BY Featured IN ('Yes') desc,
            Priority IN ('p1', 'p2', 'p3') desc
```

Could u plz spot mistake in that

Comment: What error do you see? the statement as you wrote it should work, ans so should the simplified one Yogendra Singh recommends. Are you selecting only Product_id column? it will be all NULL's in your example.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP MySQL Order by Two Columns](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/514943/php-mysql-order-by-two-columns)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try this

```
Select * from Products ORDER BY Featured, Priority
```

If you use ORDER BY on mysql enum it will not order it by alphabetically but it will order it by its position in enum.

If you want to order alphabetically as you describe cast the enum name 
to a string like this

```
Select * from Products ORDER BY  concat(Featured) desc , Priority
```

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you simply use SQL as :

```
 SELECT * 
 FROM Products
  ORDER BY Featured desc,
        Priority asc;
```

By doing this `Yes` will appear before `No`. `P1` will appear before `P2` and `P2` before `P3`. I believe, that is what you want.

If data type issue in ordering then,

```
 SELECT * 
 FROM Products
  ORDER BY CONCAT(Featured) desc,
        CONCAT(Priority) asc;
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this query--

```
 SELECT * 
 FROM Products
  ORDER BY Featured asc,Priority,ProductName asc;
```

[Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2f8fa/11)

Working code check fiddle

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT * 
    FROM Products
where Featured IN ('Yes') and
      Priority IN ('p1', 'p2', 'p3')
Order by Featured asc,Priority,ProductName asc;
```

This should work