# How to fix this mySQL code so as to show the correct output?

Tags: php, mysql

My mySQL table is as below

```
id - hash - page - timestamp
1 - ig35sdf89 - page1 - 2015-05-06 12:03:54
2 - ig35sdf89 - page2 - 2015-05-06 12:06:54
3 - ig35sdf89 - page1 - 2015-05-06 12:08:54
4 - xgd98rgf - page1 - 2015-05-06 12:10:54
5 - aaaat43gr - page3 - 2015-05-06 12:12:54
```

My question is what is a mySQL query to use so as to show something like where I will show the path of each hash order by his timestamp:

```
ig35sdf89  - page1 - 2015-05-06 12:08:54
           - page2 - 2015-05-06 12:03:54
           - page1 - 2015-05-06 12:06:54

xgd98rgf  - page1 - 2015-05-06 12:10:54

aaaat43gr  - page3 - 2015-05-06 12:12:54
```

here is the until now code

```
$sql= mysql_query("SELECT IF(@tempHash = `hash`, '', @tempHash := `hash`) `hash`, page, `timestamp` 
FROM behaviour
JOIN (SELECT @tempHash := '')s
ORDER BY `timestamp`
");

 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
     echo '<tr><td>'.$row[hash].'</td><td>'.$row[page].'</td><td>'.$row[timestamp].'</td></tr>';
 }
```

The problem is that the output even though it runs, it has a bug. The path (pages) of hash `abc` are splitted. I mean that it displays a number of pages from `abc` hash, then a user `xxx123` is shown with `xxx123` pages and then it continues with user `abc`. What I want is full list of `abc` pages, timestamps and then proceed to `xxx123` and so on.

I noticed in thatthat the splitting is made because of timestamps.

if `user1` has a page timestamp 14:10:12 and the next 14:10:30 and `user2` has 14:10:20 it will break the path of `user1`, show `user2` and then continue with `user1`.

Comment: Take a look at that question. This should solve it.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/514943/php-mysql-order-by-two-columns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    <?php

$sql= mysql_query("SELECT IF(@tempHash = `hash`, '', @tempHash := `hash`) `hash`, page, `timestamp` 
FROM behaviour
JOIN (SELECT @tempHash := '')s
ORDER BY `hash`
");

    $xhash = "";
     while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
        if($xhash != $row['hash']){
           echo '<tr><td>'.$row[hash].'</td><td>'.$row[page].'</td><td>'.$row[timestamp].'</td></tr>';
        }else{
            echo '<tr><td></td><td>'.$row[page].'</td><td>'.$row[timestamp].'</td></tr>';
        }
        $xhash = $row['hash'];
     }

    ?>
```

Comment: What is the mysql query for this?

Comment: you have use same query which in question

Comment: Thank you but isnt the bug found in the sql query? I thought that because it outputs (even kind of wrong) it should be something in the query, not in the php

Comment: give me your sql table data

Comment: I have tested your code, unfortunately I do not get any better than the previous. A sample of the sql data is in the question, first table

Comment: Now a lot of pages have no hash