# Multiple Order By in MySql Query

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am developing a voting system.
I am facing issue in ordering. 
Basically i want to get top ranking and maximum nominee first. I used "totalUserVoted" and "totalRating" in Descending order on both condition but my query ordering "totalUserVoted".

I am expecting the result in this order.

[image: Ordering Image]

Here is my sql query.

```
SELECT
  (SELECT (((SUM(`design`)*4)+(SUM(`usability`)*3)+(SUM(`creativity`)*2)+(SUM(`content`))*1))/ count(`nominee_id`) / 10
   FROM `sk_award_nominee_rating`
   WHERE `sk_award_nominee_rating`.`nominee_id`=`sk_award_nominee`.`nominee_id`) AS totalRating,
  (SELECT count(`nominee_id`)
   FROM `sk_award_nominee_rating`
   WHERE `sk_award_nominee_rating`.`nominee_id`=`sk_award_nominee`.`nominee_id`) AS totalUserVoted,
       `sk_award_nominee`.*,
       `sk_user`.`username`,
       `sk_user`.`email`,
       `sk_user_profile`.`f_name`,
       `sk_user_profile`.`m_name`,
       `sk_user_profile`.`l_name`,
       `sk_user_profile`.`address`
FROM `sk_award_nominee`
LEFT JOIN `sk_user` ON `sk_user`.`user_id`=`sk_award_nominee`.`user_id`
LEFT JOIN `sk_user_profile` ON `sk_award_nominee`.`user_id`=`sk_user_profile`.`user_id`
WHERE `sk_award_nominee`.`status` = 1
  AND DATE(approval_date) = '2016-02-22'
ORDER BY `totalUserVoted` DESC,
         `totalRating` DESC
```

Comment: Can you explain the ordering that you're trying to get? Do you want it ordered by `totalUserVoted + totalRating`?

Comment: Basically i want in the top that nominee have highest rating with maximum number of user votes.

Comment: How are rating and number of users combined in order to get the expected result? The user having the highest rating is 3rd in the expected result. How is that so?

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos Yes you are right but i want to get result on both conditions. A nominee having highest rating with maximum number of votes. For e.g. If a Nominee have AVG 7.0 rating with 1 vote, another user have 3.5 rating with 8 users and another one have 6.8 rating with 6 votes. So 6.8 rated user in the top and then 3.5 with 8 vote user and after that 7.0 with 1 vote. I want to ordering like this.

Comment: Try ORDER BY `totalUserVoted` + `totalRating` DESC

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos Thanks it will worked :). I get the result i that i am expecting.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this ?

```
ORDER BY totalUserVoted DESC, totalRating DESC
```

[PHP MySQL Order by Two Columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/514943/php-mysql-order-by-two-columns)

Comment: Please read my query firstly. I used the same thing but not getting expected result. Please take a look again on the question.