# Sort the records by date and then by project ids

Tags: mysql, sorting, sql-order-by

I want to sort the result first by date and then by id.

I used the query

```
SELECT payment_date,project_id FROM `payments` ORDER BY payment_date desc, project_id desc
```

But it did not work. I want first sort the data by date and get the project id who have max date after that records below first row show all the date based on particular project id.

like

[image]

Please help me to get the result as below:

[image]

Here is the Data table 
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f2358/5

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP MySQL Order by Two Columns](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/514943/php-mysql-order-by-two-columns)

Comment: Then you want to order by the id first and then by the date.

Comment: I already used
SELECT payment_date,project_id FROM `payments` ORDER BY project_id desc,payment_date desc .

payment_date              project_id
2016-07-25                 517
2016-07-15                 517
2016-07-08                 517
..
..
2016-07-07                 516
2016-07-30                 516
..
..
2016-07-01                 515
2016-07-24                 515

Comment: Isn't that the result you're looking for?

Answer (score 0):

I think that @Shadow is correct. Try this:

```
SELECT payment_date, project_id FROM `payments` ORDER BY project_id DESC, payment_date DESC
```

Comment: it show results

payment_date              project_id
2016-07-25                 517
2016-07-15                 517
2016-07-08                 517
..
..
2016-07-07                 516
2016-07-30                 516
..
..
2016-07-01                 515
2016-07-24                 515

Comment: That's the result you're looking for, correct? Are you looking for the result in your first or second image in your post?

Comment: NO 
I want first sort the data by date and get the project id who have max date after that records below first row show all the date based on particular project id.
like 

payment_date              project_id
2016-07-25                 517
2016-07-15                 517
2016-07-08                 517
....
2016-07-21                 514
2016-07-14                 514
..
..

Comment: result i want like in the first image .

Comment: Then just order by date only? In your result image, you have duplicates of both dates and project IDs... I think that your goal will need to be clearer for this question...

Comment: So in your result, you do not want duplicate dates. Only duplicate IDs

Comment: Duplicates records does not matters i want first latest project id
and then get all the records of that project ids  after that same for the other

Answer (score 0):

Firts order by should be payment_date (DES) and then projcet_id

```
SELECT payment_date, project_id FROM `payments` 
ORDER BY payment_date DESC, project_id DESC
```

Otherwise if you want firts order by project and the for the same project ny payment

```
SELECT payment_date, project_id FROM `payments`
ORDER BY  project_id DESC,   payment_date DESC
```

Comment: SELECT payment_date, project_id FROM `payments` ORDER BY payment_date DESC, project_id DESC

query show results as in the second image but  i want results as in the first image.

Comment: @user4328056  .. I see only one image .. please update and forma properly your question ..

Comment: No .. i have checked .. the query i provided return the (second ) image result  ......Which type is the column payment_date ?

Comment: payment_date column type is date

Comment: Sorry but i think you did not understand i want results like in first image ..like I want first sort the data by date and get the project id who have max date after that records below first row show all the date based on particular project id.
like 

payment_date              project_id
2016-07-25                 517
2016-07-15                 517
2016-07-08                 517
....
2016-07-21                 514
2016-07-14                 514
..
..

Comment: wikisend.com/download/256870/payment.sql Here is my table data file