# Order data alphabetically

Tags: php, html

I have a php table that displays the data within a mysql table.

Now the table is already in alphabetical order by Department but the users within in each Department are not.

In the example below you will see that the departments are in alphabetical order but the user data under each department is not.
Eg.

```
                           Admin Department 
                Wade        3234234     Wade@acasdaas.com
                George      3434323     George@aasdsasas.com
                          Workshop Department
                Zyiad     45454523    Zyiad@aasdasd.com
                Buffy     48282191    buffy@assad.com
```

My code:

```
<center>
<html>
<head>
<title>Extension List</title></head><body>
<br>
<h1> Alpine Motors Extension List</h1>
<h2><a href="add.php">Add Extension</a>
<br>
<br>
<form action="AlpineExtensionList.php"  method='post'>
<input type="submit" value="Print PDF"/>
<br>
<br>
<a href="delete.php"> Delete Extension</a></h2> 
<br> 
<br>
<?php
$db_host = 'localhost';
$db_user = 'root';
$db_pwd = '*****';

$database = 'list';
$table = 'users';

$conn = mysqli_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_pwd) or die("Connecting to database failed");

mysqli_select_db($conn, $database) or die("Can't select database");

// sending query
$result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT name, email, extension, phone, department FROM {$table} ORDER BY department ASC");
if (!$result) {
    die("Query to show fields from table failed");
}

echo "<table border='1'><tr>";

// printing table rows
$temp = "";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    echo "<tr>";

    if ($row['department'] != $temp){
        echo "<td colspan='4' style='text-align: center; font-weight: bold'>{$row['department']}</td></tr>\n<tr>";
        $temp = $row['department'];
    }

    echo "<td>" . $row['name'] . "</td><td>" . $row['email'] . "</td><td>" . $row['extension'] . "</td><td>" . $row['phone'] . "</td>";

    echo "</tr>\n";
}
// sending query
$result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT name, email, extension, phone, department FROM {$table} ORDER BY department ASC");
if (!$result) {
    die("Query to show fields from table failed");
}

echo "<table border='1'><tr>";

// printing table rows
$temp = "";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    echo "<tr>";

    if ($row['department'] != $temp){
        echo "<td colspan='4' style='text-align: center; font-weight: bold'>{$row['department']}</td></tr>\n<tr>";
        $temp = $row['department'];
    }

    echo "<td>" . $row['name'] . "</td><td>" . $row['email'] . "</td><td>" . $row['extension'] . "</td><td>" . $row['phone'] . "</td>";

    echo "</tr>\n";
}
mysqli_free_result($result);
echo "</table>"
?>
</h2>
</body>
</html>
</center>
```

Comment: may be duplicated http://stackoverflow.com/questions/514943/php-mysql-order-by-two-columns

Comment: That is not my question sir

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently you're just ordering by `department`:

```
ORDER BY department
```

If you want to order by additional fields, add those fields.  For example:

```
ORDER BY department, name
```

Comment: ty sir I was not aware I could set them both

Answer (score 0):

You have to order it by department and name

```
ORDER BY department, name
```