# MySQL order by a column based on another column

Tags: mysql

I have 3 tables

Table 1 (tickets):

```
id  | name
---------------
1   | Ticket 1
2   | Ticket 2
3   | Ticket 3
```

Table 2 (ticket_field):

```
id | name
------------
1  | Field 1
2  | Field 2
3  | Field 3
```

Table 3 (ticket_field_map):

```
id | ticket_id | field_id | value
------------------------------------
1  |     1     |     1    | Value 1
2  |     1     |     2    | Value 2
3  |     1     |     3    | Value 3
4  |     2     |     1    | Value 4
5  |     2     |     2    | Value 5
6  |     2     |     3    | Value 6
7  |     3     |     1    | Value 7
8  |     3     |     2    | Value 8
9  |     3     |     3    | Value 9
```

The final Table on which sorting is to be done:

```
ticket_id | ticket_name | Field 1 | Field 2 | Field 3
-----------------------------------------------------
     1    |   Ticket 1  | Value 1 | Value 2 | Value 3
     2    |   Ticket 2  | Value 4 | Value 5 | Value 6
     3    |   Ticket 3  | Value 7 | Value 8 | Value 9
```

On this table, I have to give the user option to sort on each field value.

Comment: If you asked any search engine, you would probably find this duplicate question [PHP MySQL Order by Two Columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/514943/php-mysql-order-by-two-columns)

Answer (score 2):

I think a simple two step ordering should work:

```
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
ORDER BY
    `key`, value;
```

By the way, `KEY` is a reserved MySQL keyword, and you should avoid naming your columns and tables using it.

Answer (score 0):

Use Order by key asc or desc whatever order you want