# SQL: How do I search the data with the LATEST date AND the MOST value in quantity_used?

Tags: mysql, sql

I know how to search the LATEST date and the MOST value specifically:

Most Quantity Used:

```
SELECT * FROM tour_packages
WHERE active = 1
ORDER BY quantity_used DESC
```

Latest Date:

```
SELECT * FROM tour_packages  
WHERE active = 1 
ORDER BY start_date DESC
```

But how can I do both, by able to search the LATEST date WITH the MOST value in quantity_used? Is this practice even possible?

EDITED: I think my question is not clear enough.

I intend to find the data with the LATEST date first, then from that result FIND the highest VALUE from quantity_used.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP MySQL Order by Two Columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/514943/php-mysql-order-by-two-columns)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you just want two `order by` keys:

```
SELECT tp.*
FROM tour_packages tp
WHERE tp.active = 1 
ORDER BY tp.start_date DESC, tp.quantity_used DESC;
```

This returns the rows ordered by date and within each date, the ones with the largest quantity go first.