# ordering tickets by older unanswered at the top and new answered at the bottom

Tags: mysql

i have a ticket table like this

```
tickets : id , user_id , title , has_answer(bool 0,1) , created_at
```

i want to sort my tickets by new to old (id desc) but i want unanswered tickets at the top

so i can write somethign like

```
order by has_answer asc , id desc
```

this way i get unanswered tickets at the top but they will also be sorted by id asc , i want older unanswered tickets to be shown at the top

basically i want unanswered ticket at top and sorted by `id asc` and rest of them (answered) at the bottom sorted by `id desc`

Comment: I think it will be useful in your case [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/514943/order-a-mysql-table-by-two-columns).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `id` is a numeric data type you can use conditional sorting with a `CASE` expression:

```
ORDER BY has_answer, 
         CASE WHEN has_answer THEN -id ELSE id END
```